# Rewrite equations of physics using Planck units

Tags: units

I was reading this site http://astronomy.swin.edu.au/cosmos/P/Planck+Units and in it is stated that "If we use the Planck Units, we can rewrite all of the equations of physics such that: c = G =$ \hbar $= k = 1." But I could not see how this would be possible; for example, the entropy would be $S = log W$, dimensionless?? And E = m [J] = [kg]?? Am I not getting the units wrong??

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units . It has tables keeping track of basic units,  which still exist.

Comment: but i think the answer is **yes**, you **can** rewrite all quantitative equations of physical interaction where all masses are normalized by $m_P$, all lengths or distances are normalized by $\ell_P$, all times are normalized by $t_P$, temperature is normalized by $T_P$ and every measure of electric charge is normalized by $q_P$ (**not** the elementary charge) and then $c, G, \hbar, k_B$ just go away and $\epsilon_0$ gets set to $\frac{1}{4\pi}$

Comment: personally i wish that they would have adopted a [rationalized unit convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz%E2%80%93Heaviside_units#Rationalization) so that $c=4\pi G=\hbar=k_B=\epsilon_0=1$ .  i think that would be the best and most meaningful simplification.  this would make the speed of propagation **and** the characteristic impedance of free space both equal to 1 for **both** E&M and gravity waves.  it would make the elementary charge a dimensionless value (electron charge in terms of these natural units) and in the ballpark of unity.  $e=\sqrt{4 \pi \alpha}=0.30282212$